# Can I use two different collection in one form using autoform & collection2 package in meteor?

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform, meteor-collection2

I made one form using autoForm & collection2 package in meteor. I want to add one dropdown field to that form which option is populate based on another collection i have. can i do that way?

Any advice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a template helper function to populate the options for the drop down. Define a function that returns an array of option objects, then set the `options` attribute of the select field to the name of the function.

```
Template.appInsert.helpers({
    getOptions:  function() {
        var cursor = YourCollection.find();
        return cursor.map(function(doc) {
            return {label: doc.name, value: doc._id};
        });
    }
});
```

Then use the helper function in your quick field definition:

```
{{>afQuickField name='fieldName' options=getOptions}}
```

Comment: what should be the schema for this?

fieldName : {... }

Comment: Just like any other property. It depends on your use case. Can you give an example of what you're planning to show in the drop down and how the data will be used?

Comment: can we do in this while specifying the schema itself ??

`some-schema = new SimpleSchema({
     dropdown : {
          type : String,
          label : "Select One",
          autoform : {
                options: /*....Can i do here?...*/
          }
      }
});`